# Azure DevOps Container Instance NPM Not Found

Tags: azure-devops, npm-install, azure-container-instances

I have an Azure container instance that I am using as the Azure Devops agent. I tried adding npm to the agent's dockerfile. If I connect to the container instance from the Azure portal and run `npm install -g sass`it works fine.

```
root@SandboxHost-638173989121880372:/azp# npm install -g sass

changed 17 packages in 926ms

2 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
```

My pipeline has the following task:

```
- task: Bash@3
    displayName: 'npm install sass'
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: 'npm install -g sass'
```

which fails with the following:

```
Starting: npm install sass
==============================================================================
Task         : Bash
Description  : Run a Bash script on macOS, Linux, or Windows
Version      : 3.214.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/bash
==============================================================================
Generating script.
Script contents:
npm install -g sass
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
/usr/bin/bash /azp/_work/_temp/fcfde5dd-1d1f-40c7-ba8f-9b6b3e0fb87f.sh
/azp/_work/_temp/fcfde5dd-1d1f-40c7-ba8f-9b6b3e0fb87f.sh: line 1: npm: command not found
##[error]Bash exited with code '127'.
Finishing: npm install sass
```

I'm guessing the agent must be running under some other context that can't find npm, but looking for ideas on how to resolve that.

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

#### - Basic Packages - ####
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y -qq --no-install-recommends \
    apt-transport-https \
    apt-utils \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    git \
    gnupg \
    iputils-ping \
    jq \
    lsb-release \
    software-properties-common \
    zip \
    wget && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

#### - Azure CLI and Kubectl for Azure AKS - ####
RUN curl -sL https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | bash && \
  az aks install-cli

#### - PowerShell - ####
# Download the Microsoft repository GPG keys
# Register the Microsoft repository GPG keys
# Delete the the Microsoft repository GPG keys file
# Update the list of packages after we added packages.microsoft.com
# Install PowerShell
RUN wget -q "https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb" && \
    dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb && \
    rm packages-microsoft-prod.deb && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y powershell && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

#### - Terraform CLI - ####
RUN wget -O- https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com/gpg | gpg --dearmor | tee /usr/share/keyrings/hashicorp-archive-keyring.gpg && \
    gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/hashicorp-archive-keyring.gpg --fingerprint && \
    echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/hashicorp-archive-keyring.gpg] https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com $(lsb_release -cs) main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/hashicorp.list && \
    apt update && \
    apt install -y terraform && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

#### - Docker CLI - ####
RUN mkdir -m 0755 -p /etc/apt/keyrings && \
    curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg && \
    echo \
    "deb [arch="$(dpkg --print-architecture)" signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
    "$(. /etc/os-release && echo "$VERSION_CODENAME")" stable" | \
    tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null && \
    apt update && \
    apt install -y docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-buildx-plugin docker-compose-plugin && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

#### - Npm and Node.js via NVM - ####
RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.3/install.sh | bash && \
    export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm" && \
    [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" && \
    [ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" && \
    nvm install node

# Can be 'linux-x64', 'linux-arm64', 'linux-arm', 'rhel.6-x64'.
ENV TARGETARCH=linux-x64

WORKDIR /azp

COPY ./start.sh .
RUN chmod +x start.sh

ENTRYPOINT [ "./start.sh" ]
```

***Edit - switched from using NVM to install NPM/Node directly and it worked

```
#### - Node and NPM - ####
RUN curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_20.x | bash - && \
    apt-get install -y nodejs && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Comment: I suspect it was due to using NVM so I switched to install NPM/Node directly and it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switched from using NVM to install NPM/Node directly and it worked

```
#### - Node and NPM - ####
RUN curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_20.x | bash - && \
    apt-get install -y nodejs && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```